# My calculator program in Python allows character inputs

Tags: python, error-handling, tkinter, calculator

I have created a Calculator program in Python using Tkinter and it is working fully; but when I run it you can click on the Entry box at the top of my Calculator and enter characters. I have written code so that when this happens an Error occurs but these characters still appear. I would appreciate any help on whether I can disallow this from happening.

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()

root.geometry("198x125")
root.title("Calculator")
display= tk.Entry(root, width=33, bg="pink")
display.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=5)

def click(key):
    if key =='=':
        str1="123456789"
        if display.get() [0] not in str1:
            display.insert(tk.END, "First character is not valid")
        try:
            result=eval(display.get())
            display.insert(tk.END, "="+str(result))
        except:
            display.insert(tk.END, "--> ERROR")
    elif key== 'C':
        display.delete(0, tk.END)
        if '=' in display.get():
            entry.display(0, tk.END)
    else:
        if '=' in display.get():
            display.get(0, tk.END)
        display.insert(tk.END, key)

button_list = [
'7','8','9','/',
'4','5','6','*',
'1','2','3','-',
'0','+','C','=',]
r = 2
c = 0
for t in button_list:
    cmd=lambda x=t: click(x)
    tk.Button(root, text=t, width=5, command=cmd).grid(row=r, column=c)
    c +=1
    if c > 3:
        c = 0
        r +=1

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is also created in Python 3.3 if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `state=DISABLED` option to disable the Entry while it's idle, and if you want to retain the color, just use the `disabledbackground` option:

```
display= tk.Entry(root, width=33, bg="pink", disabledbackground="pink", state=tk.DISABLED)
```

Then access its state and change it to normal at the start of the click function, and back to disabled at the end.

Refer to: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.config-method

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work, but I would try to bind the alpha keys to an event that triggers an error or a function that does the following:
gets the values from the entry box
eliminates the last item (the letter)
sets the entry value to the remaining numbers

For all practical intents and purposes it would appear to the user that they can't enter a letter.
It's probably not the most elegant solution, but I have to think it would work.